# Converting MATLAB 'imagesc' function to work with R's 'imagesc' from R's 'matlab' library

Tags: r, matlab

I am new to R, and have previously used MATLAB. I am converting a MATLAB script to operate under R. So far so good except now to plot the output graph.

## MATLAB

Here is the matlab code for plotting the graph, using `imagesc`:

`imagesc(velocity,time,myplot,[-35, 0]);`

Where:

`velocity`: 1 x 50 matrix

`time`: 1 x 10 matrix

`myplot`: 10 x 50 matrix

## Explanation of Imagesc

More details [can be found here](http://www.mathworks.com.au/help/matlab/ref/imagesc.html)

> imagesc(x,y,C) displays C as an image and specifies the bounds of the x- and y-axis with vectors x and y. If x(1) > x(2) or y(1) > y(2), the image is flipped left-right or up-down, respectively. If x and y are scalars, the image is translated to the specified location (x,y) such that the upper left corner of the image starts at (x,y).

## R

R's version of `imagesc` [which can be found here](http://rss.acs.unt.edu/Rdoc/library/matlab/html/imagesc.html)

## The Question:

How can I reproduce the data value to colormap value in the Matlab `clims` section, found here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/dHMS4.png, which is the `[-35, 0]` part of the Matlab example.

It maps data values outside of a particular range to the same color limit, effectively acting as a filter for noise on the image.

Here is the result of Matlab and R `imagesc` function without the `[-35, 0]` clims section: https://i.stack.imgur.com/F6cTz.png

As you can see they are identical.

Here is the desired result, with Matlab `[-35, 0]` section included: https://i.stack.imgur.com/oHPO4.png

Matlab of left and R on the right. The left Matlab image is what I want to produce, and it's all due to that one process `clims` `[-35, 0]` on the Matlab version of the script.

Comment: There are a few R-people with MATLAB access, but not that many. Why not describe what the imagesc function actually does? And how those parameter are interpreted?

Comment: @Dwin I have edited my original question with an explanation of imagesc

Comment: This is a good example of "What is the problem you are trying to solve?"  What you want is a certain graph, so don't ask how to make a particular tool produce that graph: ask how to get from your data to the desired output.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft No I really just want that tool to produce the same as what the tool that Matlab uses. If it did that, we wouldn't be here :) I guess if you're after more specific, the `[-35, 0]` part is where I cannot reproduce in R - named `clims` from the link provided.

Comment: Here is the section http://i.imgur.com/eVy6V8N.png, where it maps a data value to a color value outside of the range.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft I have edited my question with a base question.

Comment: To deal with the range limit, do something like `mymatrix[mymatrix < -35] <- -35`  and similar for your desired maximum value.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft I have tried your solution, unfortunately the same results. 

Here is the result of Matlab and R `imagesc` function without the `[-35, 0]` clims section: http://i.imgur.com/DzDjrzu.png

As you can see they are identical.

Here is the desired result, with Matlab `[-35, 0]` section included: http://i.imgur.com/Qbx6jNI.png

Matlab of left and R on the right. The left Matlab image is what I want to produce, and it's all due to that one process `clims` `[-35, 0]` on the Matlab version of the script.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I reckon you can get the same effect as `clims` by pre-processing your data so that values outside the range are squeezed to the range limits.

```
z = matrix(rnorm(10*10, sd=3), 10)

z2 <- z
z2[z2 > 3] <- 3
z2[z2 < -5] <- -5

# or simply
z2 = scales::squish(z, c(-5, 3))

filled.contour(z)
```

[image]

```
filled.contour(z2)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

As I read the question and the linked material and some other material found with Google, you want the combined capacities of the `image` and `axis` functions in R. Some of the other material said that `imagesc` really only relabels the axis annotation. (And it has some additional color scaling capacity that you don't seem to be requesting.)  Reading images in from files may take some extra packages. There is a `grImport` package with useful capabilities for pdf. There are also packages that specialize in particular formats, eg. `tiff` or `rtiff`. If you have a modes sized matrix to plot, you should offer `dput(mat)`. In the absence of an example and specific directions can offer this adaptation of an example in the middle of the Examples section of `?image`.

```
> image(t(volcano)[ncol(volcano):1,])   # the default axes lebeling

 image(t(volcano)[ncol(volcano):1,], axes=FALSE)
 axis(1, at=seq(0,1,.1), labels= seq(0,100,10) )
 axis(2, at=seq(0,1,.1), labels= rev( seq(0,100,10)) )
```

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately, I must use `imagesc` as it has the `clims` function the `[-35, 0]` part where it normalizes the matrix. I just can't seem to find how I can do it on the R version. Unless you know how to normalize a matrix between that range `[-35, 0]`.

Comment: >You can expand midrange color resolution by mapping low values to the first color and high values to the last color in the colormap by specifying color value limits (clims). If the size of the current colormap is 81-by-3, the statements

>clims = [ 10 60 ]
>imagesc(C,clims)

>map the data values in C

Comment: this section: http://i.imgur.com/eVy6V8N.png, where it maps a data value to a color value, specifically when it falls outside of the range specified

Comment: You can flip axes with xlim/ylim, just IYI  image(x = seq(0, 100, length = ncol(volcano)), y = seq(0, 100, length = nrow(volcano)), t(volcano)[ncol(volcano):1, nrow(volcano):1], ylim = c(100, 0), xlab = "", ylab = "")

Comment: @mdsummer so where do I substitute the `[-35,0]` data map to colormap values?

Comment: @mdsummer did you look at the image I provided - it needs to map the colors at the end of each spectrum to values in the matrix that fall outside or a specific range